# Give the corresponding elementary matrix decomposition of A

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

can you guys explain the question to me

Put the following matrices into reduced row echelon form, indicating the row operations you use. Give the corresponding elementary matrix decomposition of A

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc}
      2&1&1\\
      1&2&1\\
      1&1&2
    \end{array}
\right] $$

i put the matrix in RREF form, but i dont know how to get the elementary matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you perform elementary row operations, you are multiplying the matrix by an elementary matrix.

Suppose you perform $k$ operations.

$$E_k\ldots E_1A=R$$

Then we have 
$$A=E_1^{-1}\ldots E_k^{-1}R$$

To get the elmentary matrix, perform the same operation on the identity matrix.

Suppose the first operation is multiply the first row by $\frac12$.

$$E_1=\begin{bmatrix} \frac12 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

$E_1^{-1}$ can be obtained by thinking about what is the reverse operation? It should be multiply the first row by $2$.

$$E_1^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: what are E1, E2, ....?

Comment: The elementary matrices. To obtain them, perform the row operations on identity matrix.